# Why don't I have the copy editor badge?

Tags: support, bug

I just looked at this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all&search=abe+miessler

And it says I have 726 edits.  According to the badge description:

> Edited 500 posts

It seems like I should have it.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think that edits to your own posts count towards the copy editor badge but do in the editor stats.

Comment: When you go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/) what you see in the progress towards the badge?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, sorry how would I find the progress towards the badge on that page?

Comment: @animuson, thanks for the link.  Most of my edits are tag related so I'm guessing I'm getting caught up on the `Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count` rule.

Comment: @AbeMiessler: Click into any of the queues and click on the progress bar at the top of that page.

Comment: @Rory:  If they did, I'd have 100 copy editor badges.  You know, ... if you could have more than one...

Answer (score 6):

Edits that you make on your own posts, or edits where you add/remove tags, do not count towards the "Copy Editor" badge.