# Progress on copy editor badge

Tags: support, edit-badges

I've read this already: [Why don't I have the copy editor badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/why-dont-i-have-the-copy-editor-badge)

Recently I went on a mass retagging effort to clean up [timeline](/questions/tagged/timeline) from [facebook-timeline](/questions/tagged/facebook-timeline), so I'm not sure how many edits I have where I have edited something in addition to or apart from the post tags.

However, the progress meter on the review page seems to indicate that I have already earned the badge:

[image: badge progress meter]

Yet I still have no gold badges. It says 515 here but under my revisions I see 723 so I assume that 208 of them are either pure retagging or multiple edits made to the same post (if that matters)?

Is this a bug in the progress meters and if so, is there a way to check my actual progress for the badge?

Comment: Do you know how long ago is you hit 500 in this meter?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Sometime this morning, so within the past two hours.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I just found it strange that the Archaeologist badge showed up instantly but not this one, but I guess I will wait and see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Counting backwards on your current edits, it looks like [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18510719/3) put you at 500 (not counting retag only posts) and that was about 2 1/2 hours ago.  So I'd say just be patient and wait for the script to run.

But it looks like you earned [the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/223/copy-editor?userid=404623) over an hour ago (15:57 UTC) according to the timestamp, which was only 15 minutes after you asked this question.

As mentioned, you need to be patient with badges.  Very few are awarded instantly and there are several that can take several hours.  The jobs that award the badges all run at different intervals.  More often than not, it is best to wait until the next day before wondering where you badge is,